# Htmlparser can not parse "tbody" in Java

Tags: java, html-parser

In `org.htmlparser` I want to  get `tbody` node by `id`

```
Parser htmlParser =  Parser.createParser("<table id='_table' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' class='tableRegion' width='100%' ><thead><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr></thead><tbody id='_table_body' ><tr><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr></tbody></table>","gbk"); 
NodeFilter filter = new HasAttributeFilter("id", "_table_body"); 
NodeFilter f = new AndFilter(new TagNameFilter("tr"), new HasParentFilter(filter)); 
NodeList nodelist1 = htmlParser.parse(filter); //Tag (144[0,144],173[0,173]): tbody id='_table_body' 
NodeList nodelist2 = htmlParser.parse(f); //
```

Why doesn't `nodelist1` read `<tr><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>`?

Answer (score 0):

If you get the `<tbody>` node, you should expect to have:

```
<tbody id='_table_body' ><tr><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr></tbody>
```

rather than

```
<tr><td>4</td><td>5</td>
```

The latter is a child node of the `<tbody>` element ... not the element itself.  Basically, your code (using `filter`) looks like it is giving you the right stuff.

Comment: but actually，nodelist1's result is "tbody id='_table_body' ",not "<tbody id='_table_body' ><tr><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr></tbody>"

Comment: Are you sure that's not just an artifact of the way you are displaying it?  `"tbody id='_table_body'"` is not a Node.